# OpenCV (Emgu.CV) -- compositing images with alpha

Tags: image-processing, opencv, emgucv, alphablending

I'm using Emgu.CV to perform some basic image manipulation and composition. My images are loaded as `Image<Bgra,Byte>`.

**Question #1:** When I use the `Image<,>.Add()` method, the images are always blended together, regardless of the alpha value. Instead I'd like them to be composited one atop the other, and use the included alpha channel to determine how the images should be blended. So if I call `image1.Add(image2)` any fully opaque pixels in image2 would completely cover the pixels from image1, while semi-transparent pixels would be blended based on the alpha value.

Here's what I'm trying to do in visual form. There's a city image with some "transparent holes" cut out, and a frog behind. This is what it should look like:

[image]

And this is what openCV produces.

[image: This is what OpenCV (Emgu.CV) produces when I call "add"]

How can I get this effect with OpenCV? And will it be as fast as calling `Add()`?

**Question #2:** is there a way to perform this composition in-place instead of creating a new image with each call to `Add()`?  (e.g. `image1.AddImageInPlace(image2)` modifies the bytes of  `image1`?)

**NOTE**: Looking for answers within Emgu.CV, which I'm using because of how well it handles perspective warping.

Comment: Hey. Is there a way you can provide us with those two images so that we can try to reproduce? Thx!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Before OpenCV 2.4 there was no support of PNGs with alpha channel.**

To verify if your current version supports it, print the number of channels after loading an image that you are certain to be RGBA. If it supports, the application will output the number 4, else it will output number 3 (RGB). Using the C API you would do:

```
IplImage* t_img = cvLoadImage(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
if (!t_img)
{
    printf("!!! Unable to load transparent image.\n");
    return -1;
}
printf("Channels: %d\n", t_img->nChannels);
```

**If you can't update OpenCV**:

- [There are](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8280564/176769) [some posts](https://web.archive.org/web/20120909192400/http://blog.developer.stylight.de/2010/05/how-to-load-alpha-channel-pngs-with.html) around that try to bypass this limitation but I haven't tested them myself;
- The easiest solution would be to use another API to load the image and blend it, check [blImageBlending](http://www.barbato.us/2010/12/01/blimageblending-emulating-photoshops-blending-modes-opencv/);
- Another alternative, not as lightweight, is to [use](http://www.idevelopsoftware.com/2008/03/use-qimage-to-create-a-composite-image-ie-one-image-with-another-overlaid-on-top-of-it/) [**Qt**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4379632/176769).

**If your version already supports PNGs with RGBA**:

- Take a look at [Emulating photoshop’s blending modes in OpenCV](http://www.barbato.us/2010/12/01/blimageblending-emulating-photoshops-blending-modes-opencv/). It implements several [Photoshop blending modes](http://www.northlite.net/ps/blend.htm) and I imagine you are capable of converting that code to .Net.

**EDIT:**

### I had to deal with this problem recently and I've demonstrated how to deal with it on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20673435/176769).

Comment: I don't understand your edit.  What do displacement maps have to do with alpha blending?

Comment: [The implementation of "displacement map filter" overlays 2 images](https://github.com/karlphillip/GraphicsProgramming/blob/master/cvDisplacementMapFilter/main.cpp), i.e. blends them together, according to alpha channel values.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to iterate through each pixel. I'm assuming image 1 is the frog image, and image 2 is the city image, with image1 always being bigger than image2.

```
//to simulate image1.AddInPlace(image2)
 int image2w = image2.Width;
 int image2h = image2.Height;
 int i,j;
 var alpha;
 for (i = 0; i < w; i++)
 {
     for (j = 0; j < h; j++)
     {
           //alpha=255 is opaque > image2 should be used
           alpha = image2[3][j,i].Intensity;
           image1[j, i] 
               = new Bgra(
               image2[j, i].Blue * alpha + (image1[j, i].Blue * (255-alpha)),
               image2[j, i].Green * alpha + (image1[j, i].Green * (255-alpha)),
               image2[j, i].Red * alpha + (image1[j, i].Red * (255-alpha)));
      }
 }
```

Comment: I'm also assuming image1 is a BGR image, not BGRA

Comment: `image2[j, i].Blue * alpha` will overflow beyond 255 very often, same goes for your green and red calculations.

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting blog post on internet, which I think is related to what you are trying to do.

Please have a look at the [Creating Overlays Method](http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/transparent-image-overlays-in-opencv/) ([archive.org link](https://web.archive.org/web/20100710151657/http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/transparent-image-overlays-in-opencv/)). You can use this idea to implement your own function to add two images in the way you mentioned above, making some particular areas in the image transparent while leaving the rest as it is.

Comment: the link has gone

Answer (score 0):

Using Osiris's suggestion as a starting point, and having checked out alpha compositing on Wikipedia, i ended up with the following which worked really nicely for my purposes.

This was used this with Emgucv. I was hoping that the opencv gpu::AlphaComposite methods were available in Emgucv which I believe would have done the following for me, but alas the version I am using didn't appear to have them implemented.

```
static public Image<Bgra, Byte> Overlay( Image<Bgra, Byte> image1, Image<Bgra, Byte> image2 )
        {

            Image<Bgra, Byte> result = image1.Copy();
            Image<Bgra, Byte> src = image2;
            Image<Bgra, Byte> dst = image1;

            int rows = result.Rows;
            int cols = result.Cols;
            for (int y = 0; y < rows; ++y)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < cols; ++x)
                {
                    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing
                    double  srcA = 1.0/255 * src.Data[y, x, 3];
                    double dstA = 1.0/255 * dst.Data[y, x, 3];
                    double outA = (srcA + (dstA - dstA * srcA));
                    result.Data[y, x, 0] = (Byte)(((src.Data[y, x, 0] * srcA) + (dst.Data[y, x, 0] * (1 - srcA))) / outA);  // Blue
                    result.Data[y, x, 1] = (Byte)(((src.Data[y, x, 1] * srcA) + (dst.Data[y, x, 1] * (1 - srcA))) / outA);  // Green
                    result.Data[y, x, 2] = (Byte)(((src.Data[y, x, 2] * srcA) + (dst.Data[y, x, 2] * (1 - srcA))) / outA); // Red
                    result.Data[y, x, 3] = (Byte)(outA*255);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

A newer version, using emgucv methods. rather than a loop. Not sure it improves on performance. 
            double unit = 1.0 / 255.0;
            Image[] dstS = dst.Split();
            Image[] srcS = src.Split();
            Image[] rs = result.Split();

```
        Image<Gray, double> srcA = srcS[3] * unit;
        Image<Gray, double> dstA = dstS[3] * unit;
        Image<Gray, double> outA = srcA.Add(dstA.Sub(dstA.Mul(srcA)));// (srcA + (dstA - dstA * srcA));

        // Red.
        rs[0] = srcS[0].Mul(srcA).Add(dstS[0].Mul(1 - srcA)).Mul(outA.Pow(-1.0)); // Mul.Pow is divide.
        rs[1] = srcS[1].Mul(srcA).Add(dstS[1].Mul(1 - srcA)).Mul(outA.Pow(-1.0));
        rs[2] = srcS[2].Mul(srcA).Add(dstS[2].Mul(1 - srcA)).Mul(outA.Pow(-1.0));
        rs[3] = outA.Mul(255);

        // Merge image back together.
        CvInvoke.cvMerge(rs[0], rs[1], rs[2], rs[3], result);
        return result.Convert<Bgra, Byte>();
```

Comment: Note, this is actually a terrible function, that when analysed represented 80% of the cpu usage.