# Alpha Blending in Emgu CV

Tags: alphablending, emgucv, computer-vision

Hi I am learning Emgu CV. I would like to perform alpha blend(addWeighted). I have the following codes

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> image = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(filename);
Image<Gray, Byte> grayImage = image.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
Image<Bgr, Byte> blendImage;
```

How to alpha blend these two images? (Bgr and Gray)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958473/opencv-emgu-cv-compositing-images-with-alpha) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the grayscale image back to color and then blend them.

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> grayBGRImage = grayImage.Convert<Bgr, Byte>();
double alpha = 0.5; // Or however you would like to blend them
double beta = 1 - alpha;
double gamma = 0;
Image<Bgr, Byte> blendImage = image.AddWeighted(grayBGRImage, alpha, beta, gamma);
```